# Why can't we obtain the values of fundemental constants like the charge of an electron theoretically?

Tags: electrons, nuclear-physics

Why can't we obtain the values of fundemental constants like the charge of an electron theoretically ? By solving an equation or something rather than performing the Oil drop experiment.

Comment: A theoretical model makes statements on structure the mechanisms, which is behind a certain phenomenon. Most models try to limit their number of free parameters $n$ to be more appealing, meaning, that the less free parameters a model has, the more predictive it is, because you need to measure only  $n$ times before you can make predictions about experiments. The best model we have at the moment (the standard model) has free parameters of order 10. But an experimentally tested model with zero free parameters has not been discovered yet.

Comment: @DomDoe That looks like an answer, not a comment.